# ASP.NET application opening WAY too many SQL connections

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, connection-pooling, application-pool

I have an issue on a codebit with an ASP.NET Webforms 4 application.
I am using SQL server 2008 R2, IIS 7, the website is running on Windows Server 2008 R2 in separate Application pool (integrated mode, .NET4, with support for 32bit assemblies).

The following code is posing problems:

```
Dim sqlCmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand
With sqlCmd
    Using sqlConnectionToUse As SqlClient.SqlConnection = GetActiveConnexion(pstrConnectString), _
        vAdaptor As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter

            .Connection = sqlConnectionToUse

            .CommandText = pstrSQL 'function parameter

            vAdaptor.SelectCommand = sqlCmd
            'query1: SELECT somecolumn FROM table WHERE somecolumn '' ==> opens a new connection in SQL Server
            'query2: SELECT someothercolumn FROM anothertable WHERE someothercolumn 23 ==> uses my WebSite process active connection
            vAdaptor.Fill(vDataSet)
    End Using
End With
```

**UPDATE:** the GetActiveConnexion() method simply does the following code in my case:

```
Return New SqlClient.SqlConnection("my connection string obtained from the web.config file")
```

When I run the query2, everything goes smoothly, the ASP.NET application uses the openned connection of the application pool and I get my results in the dataset.

However, whenever I run the query1, a NEW connection is openned in SQL server (I can see it show up in the SSMS's Activity Monitor) and this one remains openned. The problem is that If I run this query1 100 times, I reach the connection pool's limit and very bad things happens. I still gets the results in the dataset, can use them etc...
The new connection is created on the call of vAdaptator.Fill().

Any idea on what's wrong ?

Thanks a lot for your time.
(PS: sorry for the bad english).

Here is the code in C# for those who prefer:

```
object sqlCmd = new SqlClient.SqlCommand();
using (SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConnectionToUse = GetActiveConnexion(pstrConnectString)) {
    using (SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter vAdaptor = new SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter()) {

        sqlCmd.Connection = sqlConnectionToUse;

        sqlCmd.CommandText = pstrSQL; //function parameter

        vAdaptor.SelectCommand = sqlCmd;
        //query1: SELECT F10_ID FROM FIN_MONTANT_TT_F10 WHERE F10_ID_TT_F19 = '' ==> opens a new connection in SQL Server
        //query2: SELECT A48_ID FROM ADH_EPARTICIPANT_ADMIN_A48 WHERE A48_ID=23 ==> uses my WebSite process active connection
        vAdaptor.Fill(vDataSet);
    }
}
```

Comment: is the connection string always the same? From what is see is that the query1 uses a test field in the where clause that could cause some troubles if no proper index exists...

Comment: I think we need to see the logic of `GetActiveConnexion()` - are you explicitly opening/closing the connections to be used?

Comment: connection pooling depends on the exact same connection string. did you check your pstrConnectString variable in terms of query1?? what is the exact pstrConnectString when you execute query1?

Comment: I just addded the GetActiveConnexion logic, it is very simple in my case. And no, I am not explicitly openning closinh the connections. The using do that (calling dispose on both the adapater and the connection) as well as the vAdaptor.Fill (which opens and closes the connections).

Comment: The connection string is always the same. I get it from the web.config file so I shouldn't change. I will check on that still.

Comment: Try to switch order so that the connection is created first and then the command. `Dim command = connection.CreateCommand()`. And wrap the command with `using` too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SqlCommand` instance should be wrapped in a using block as it's Disposable. It's probably the source of your problems.

```
using (SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConnectionToUse = GetActiveConnexion(pstrConnectString)) 
{
    using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = sqlConnectionToUse.CreateCommand())
    {
        using (SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter vAdaptor = new SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter()) 
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Or VB

```
Using sqlConnectionToUse As SqlClient.SqlConnection = GetActiveConnexion(pstrConnectString)
    Using sqlCmd As SqlCommand = sqlConnectionToUse.CreateCommand()
        Using vAdaptor As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter()
                ...
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Just added that, it is effectivly better for the code by my problem is still here.

EDIT: my using were not in the same order though, i'll give it another try. Maybe the sqlConnectionToUse.CreateCommand() can help.

Comment: The code above shouldn't cause the issue, are you sure you're not just seeing connections as a result of connection pooling? After disposing SqlCommand does it still grow?

Comment: it does indeed helps. however, I am still around 15 Connections. I am using a synclock around this code block (which something I forgot to add in the code snippets), could this be that I have still have a few threads waiting to execute the code and therefore, keeping the connections open ? The Usings are inside the syncklock though (so the connection shouldn't be opened if the lock is taken).

Comment: 15 could well be connection pooling, if it's not growing like it was before you are prob OK. Synclock is only an issue if you lock after creating the connection. If you're just wrapping this code within a synclock implementation then that should be fine (you should have a good reason for using synclock obviously).

Comment: I let the code run multiple times, and the 15 connections are steady (it actually is only 12 connections, 2 of them are SSMS queries and one if from another application).However, after I change code (ie navigate on other page, do other requests that do not cause the supposed connection pooling), the 12 connections remains active. Should I be worried by that or should I just go read some more articles about connection pooling on MSDN ?

Comment: Yep worth reading up on, but I don't think it's anything to be concerned about. App pooling maintains a number of active connections to the database in order to reduce the overhead when they are required. By default I believe there can be up to 100 connections in the pool ready to go.